# Date Manipulation Not Working Correctly

Tags: php, date

I am trying to change a date displayed in this format "d/m/Y" into this format "d-m-Y", and I wrote the code below:

```
//Add $license years to today
$today = date("j-m-Y");
$license = $row_customize['license'];
$startdate = $row_customize['startdate'];
list($d,$m,$Y) = explode('/',$startdate);
$newstartDate = $d."-".$m."-".$Y;
$enddate= date("j-m-Y", strtotime("$newstartDate +$license years"));
echo $today;
echo $enddate;
```

$today displayed correctly, but $enddate is showing me a date in 1970 e.g 1-01-1970.

Please what have I done wrong?

Comment: Probably not your problem, but if you're looking for an unambiguous date format to format into, always use Y-m-d, not d-m-Y, as "03-05-2013" means "5th March", not "3rd May" in the USA.

Answer (score 0):

I would put

```
$newstartDate = $d."-".$m."-".(intval($Y)+intval($license));
$enddate= date("j-m-Y", strtotime($newstartDate));
```

I think the format `"<date> + n years"` is not allowed for strtotime()

Comment: maybe print values of $license, $startDate and $newStartDate. They can help you (and/or us) to understand what is going wrong.

Comment: I printed the values, they all came out correct as expected, except $enddate which still remained 1970

Answer (score 0):

The default date is 0 which equates to 01-01-1970. So both $newstartDate and $license years are 0 so when added together the result is still 0. So the questions are why is $newstartDate and $license set to 0.

I think like p91paul said you may not be able to use n Years. I think also $newstartDate may be in an unsupported format. Could you use $startDate in the function and then perform the format change after?